# Ipdb and method documentation

Tags: python, ipython, pdb

I have to analyze methods a foreign API, and how I usually do it it to write a test script, or find an example code, do a

```
ipdb.set_trace()
```

Where I want to experiment, and than take a look at currently available variables, objects and their methods. However, when I want to check the documentation the way Ipython offers

```
object.method?
```

I get

```
*** SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<stdin>, line 1)
```

---

If I try

```
help(object.method)
```

It gives

```
*** No help on (object.method)
```

---

Does that mean that there is no documentation for the selected method, or am I using the wrong way of calling it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `help()` function is actually a wrapper around `pydoc.help()` which means that you can do something like:

```
ipdb> import math
ipdb> import pydoc
ipdb> pydoc.help(math.log)
```

Answer (score 9):

Actually `!help(object.method)` works, you just need to signify with `!` that it's a python command, not *ipdb* help command. Though convenient question mark doesn't work that way unfortunately.

Comment: Does not seem to work in Python 3.6.5 with IPython 6.4.0. It takes me to bash.