# When using the 'len' function, where does it return the answer to?

Tags: python

I am working through the crash course Python book, and the exercise is using the 'len' function.

I type in

```
cars=['bmw', 'audi', 'toyota', 'subaru']
len(cars)
```

but then what?  Am I supposed to add the >>> in front of those lines as pictured in the book?  I tried that too, but I still did not get any answer.  And is it supposed to show up under the line or down in the preview window? And also yes, I did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> for print.  That did nothing as well.

I am using Sublime to learn Python.

[image]

[image]

Comment: >> tells me you're on a python terminal in which case no, those are added by the console directly. You just have to enter your python code/commands

Comment: Also the part `len(cars)` go on a separate line that will start with `>>` after you hit enter post typing the first line.

Comment: It sounds like the tutorial expects you to be in the standard python interactive shell, but you aren't -- you're in an IDE (such as VS Code or PyCharm) or a text editor.

Comment: What are you running the code in? I haven't read this book myself so I'm not sure what it would have told you up to this point. It sounds like you're using an editor but the book is saying to use a Python shell (AKA REPL). Plus, if you're running the code with the `>>>` in the code itself, you should get a syntax error, not just nothing. Please [edit] to clarify. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: Try this: `print(len(cars))`.  You seem to have forgotten to use the `print` function to *display* the length.

Comment: You want to run in an interactive console. See [In Python, how do I debug with an interactive command line...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547049/in-python-how-do-i-debug-with-an-interactive-command-line-and-visual-breakpoin)

Comment: This must be a mega duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

The `>>>` in the examples in your book is showing the default prompt for [Python's interactive mode](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode).

This is generally entered in a shell session or terminal by running the command `python` or `python3` without any arguments (or with an explicit `-i` argument, e.g. `python3 -i`). It will start by printing a message like this, and waiting for you to type something:

```
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

You can then type a line of Python, which will be executed immediately, and the result automatically printed. This is sometimes called a "REPL" for "Read, Evaluate, Print, Loop".

So in this case as soon as you enter the second line, `len(cars)`, and hit enter, it will print `4`.

This is just a convenient way of playing with the basics of a language, without having to save a file, run inside a web server, etc. Inside a full Python script you would either explicitly output it, with `print( len(cars) )`, or use it in some other way, e.g. assign a new variable like `number_of_cars = len(cars)`

Comment: the `-i` option is not necessary unless you are running a script, and then want to drop in to an interactive session, e.g. `python -i myscript.py`. so normally just `python` would suffice

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just do len(cars) as >>> means that it is in the terminal. To get the actual output, use this:

```
print(len(cars))
```

or you could use

```
variable = len(cars)
print(variable)
```

Other than terminal, you could use a Jupiter Notebook, but since you seem new, you should stick to Sublime text

Comment: there are many more examples, but they are not as common as the above few.

Comment: Re *"You cannot just do len(cars) as >>> means that it is in the terminal."*. Why not? Isn't it the other way around? It prints "4" just fine in the Python shell (that has "`>>>`" as the prompt). Tested with Python 3.8.10 (interactive).

Comment: what I meant was that len(cars) by itself only works in the terminal or Jupiter Notebook. Otherwise you have to do what I said